# How to print float variable from Trace32 with python command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, trace32, lauterbach

I have a simple C code which will update static variable with floating variable. Let's say I have

```
static float32  totalcount = 60.73f;
```

I want to know how to get float values from `Lauterbach trace32`. I have tried to print the `float` values using below `t32api64.dll` and `ctype` method.

```
error =  ctypes.c_int32(0)
result = ctypes.c_float32(0)

 t32api.T32_Cmd (b"InterCom mycore Var totalcount")
    error = t32api.T32_EvalGet(ctypes.byref(result));
    if (error == 0):
        print("OK");
        print (result.value)
    else:
        print("Nok error")
```

But I am getting some different ouputt.

**Output:**

```
$ python test.py
OK
8.96831017167883e-44
```

After some research, I understood that `t32api.T32_EvalGet()` function is not supporting `float` values. So I would like to know how to print the float values from `trace32` using python. Please suggest some method to print float values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `T32_ExecuteFunction_Double()` or `T32_EvalGetString()`:

Example for `int T32_ExecuteFunction_Double(const char *pExpression, char *pBuffer, uint32_t BufferSize, double *pResult)`

```
error =  ctypes.c_int32(0)
buffer = (ctypes.c_char * 4096)()
result = ctypes.c_float32(0)
error = t32api.T32_ExecuteFunction(b'Var.FVALUE("totalcount")', buffer, len(buffer), result))
print('Var.FVALUE("totalcount"):, "{result.value}")
```

Example for `int T32_ReadVariableString(const char *symbol, char *string, int maxlen)`

```
error =  ctypes.c_int32(0)
buffer = (ctypes.c_char * 4096)()
error = t32api.T32_Cmd(b"Eval Var.STRing(totalcount)")
error = t32api.T32_EvalGetString(buffer, len(buffer))
if error == 0:
    print(b"Eval Var.STRing(totalcount):", float(buffer.value))
```

---

Example using the [pyrcl](https://pypi.org/project/lauterbach-trace32-rcl/) package:

```
import lauterbach.trace32.rcl as t32

with t32.connect() as dbg:
    variable = dbg.variable.read("totalcount")
    print(variable.value)
    # or
    variable = dbg.fnc("Var.FVALUE(totalcount)")
    print(variable)
```

Comment: If "totalcount" is a structure variable, How to decode it in py file (read.variable returns hex value). Is there any function or command available?